# Making things happen over time python

Tags: python, time

I have trying to get a hunger variable to increase by one very three minutes, while I have other code running. Using time.sleep() just stops the entire code. Is there a way to do this?

```
Hunger=1
If Hunger=1:
    sleep(180)
    Hunger-=1
```

Comment: It is wrong syntax: `If` -> `if`; in statement `=` -> `==`. And use spaces before and after operator (PEP 8 convention)

Comment: What is the context of this code? Is it a game with a 60 fps loop, such as with pygame, or a console program?

Comment: If you want the hunger variable to _increase_ why are you subtracting one from it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for threading:

```
import thread, time

hunger = 0

def decreaseHunger():
    global hunger
    while True:
        time.sleep(180)
        hunger -= 1

thread.start_new_thread(decreaseHunger, ())

# you can do other stuff here, and it will continue to decrease hunger
# every 2 minutes, while the other stuff happens as well
```

Comment: I think `global` is needed when assigning to the global variables.

Comment: Since `hunger` is likely a global and will also be accessed by the main thread, this thread and it need to use a `thread.LockType` or `threading.Lock` object to serialize concurrent access to its value.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a lot of these types of things to run asynchronously and it's a large project, you could consider using an asynchronous task queue library like celery (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html).  Of course, it might be too much overhead - no idea what your project is trying to do.

You would define a task called `increase_hunger`, e.g.:

```
@celery.task
def increase_hunger():
hunger=1
while True:
    sleep(180)
    hunger+=1
```

From your main code, calling `add_hunger.apply_async()` will launch this task from another place.  For details on exactly where to put the task code and how to set up a celery project, you should work through the tutorial.

An alternative would be to use something like celery beat (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) to do this as a periodic background task, but that doesn't sound like your use case.